# PHP: autoload class not found

Tags: php, spl-autoloader

I have a problem autoloading classes in PHP.

In my `index.php` I write (that's the simpliest one):

```
function _autoload($class_name) {
  require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$a = new Cont();
```

My `Cont.php` file is located at `PROJECT_ROOT/assets/core/Contr.php`;

As a result my `index.php` file throws a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cont' not found in /var/www/bill/index.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `__autoload()` seems like you missed an underscore character.

That is..

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
  require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$a = new Cont();
```

A tip from the [PHP Manual...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

> spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is
>   discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's `__autoload` - two underscores.

Second, that technique is discouraged - [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) is a better option.

Third, you'll probably need `require_once 'assets/core/' . $class_name . '.php';` if your files are in `PROJECT_ROOT/assets/core`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for a dumb mistake - did not spotted a missing underscore.